# use function sql with orm magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to display orders that are in status pending 4 days after the creation date.

In sql this work with this => `SELECT * FROM sales_flat_order where DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL 4 DAY) and status = pending;`

But with orm in magento this not work why ?

```
  $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending')
                ->addFieldToFilter('updated_at',  new Zend_Db_Expr("DATE_ADD('updated_at', INTERVAL 4 DAY)"));
```

that does not give me the result I expect from my sql query at the top.

Can you help me please

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you can't use addFieldToFilter to add a DB Expression. You will need to modify the base query by fetching the select.

```
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Order_Collection $collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending');
$collection->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("DATE_ADD('updated_at', INTERVAL 4 DAY)"));

var_dump((string) $collection->getSelect());
```

You can also print the query by casting to string the getSelect which make it easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you Oliver de Cramer, but i need to return collection for send email. When i debug $collection, i don't have information of order.

Answer (score 0):

**=> This is your code**

```
public function getCollectionStandByPayement(){


$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending');
$collection->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("DATE_ADD('updated_at', INTERVAL 4 DAY)"));

    return $collection;


}
```

**and**

```
 public function getOrderStandByPayement() {

    foreach ($this->getCollectionStandByPayement() as $order) {

        Mage::log('N° = ' .$order->getIncrementId() .' - '. $order->getCreatedAt(), null, 'getOrderStandByPayement.log', true);
        $this->sendEmailStandByPayement($order);    
    }
}
```

when I debug `$collection` I don't have information of order